# How to design URL to return data from the current user in a REST API?

Tags: rest, restful-authentication

I have a REST based service where a user can return a list of their own books (this is a private list).

The URL is currently `../api/users/{userId}/books`

With each call they will also be supplying an authentication token supplied earlier.

My question(s) is:

1. Is supplying the `userId` in the URL redundant? As we get a token with each call we can find out which user is performing the call and return their list of books. The `userId` is not strictly required.
2. Would removing the `userId` break REST principles as `/users/books/` looks like it should return all books for all users?
3. Should I just bite the bullet and authenticate them against the token and then check that the token belongs to the same `userId`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Short answer

You could use `me` in the URL to refer to the *current user*. With this approach, you would have a URL as following: `/users/me/books`.

### An answer for each question

> Is supplying the `userId` in the URL redundant? As we get a token with each call we can find out which user is performing the call and return their list of books. The `userId` is not strictly required.

You could consider doing something like this: `/users/me/books`. Where `me` refers to the *current user*.  It's easier to understand than `/users/books`, which can be used to return all books from the users.

For some flexibility, besides `/users/me/books`, you could support `/users/{userId}/books`.

The URL `/users/me` can be used to return data from the current user. Many APIs, such as [StackExchange](https://api.stackexchange.com/docsa), [Facebook](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-current-users-profile/), [Spotify](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-current-users-profile/) and [Google+](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) adopt this approach.

> Would removing the `userId` break REST principles as `/users/books/` looks like it should return all books for all users?

I don't think it will break any REST principles, but I think your resources will not be properly indetified. As I answered above, I would use `/users/me/books` and also support `/users/{userId}/books`.

> Should I just bite the bullet and authenticate them against the token and then check that the token belongs to the same `userId`?

When using the `userId` in the URL to request private information from a user, there's no harm in checking if the token belongs to the user with the `userId` included in the URL.

Comment: I like the look of `/me` very much, and if other large APIs are following the same principle then I'm happy to use it. Thanks very much!

Comment: facebook link seems broken, and google+ apparently deprecated

Comment: It's gonna break all your cache mecanisms, since one route can return several datas. So it's not really REST compliant. Consider to read this answer: https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/477#issuecomment-752997774, on my side, I use `/users/me?id=ID_CONNECTED_USER` and match both token & id, my route is unique, I can cache it.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think that removing userId would break any REST principles, because after all, /users and them /books, its a little bit openend to interpretation and REST says basically nothing about it, on the other way if you are going to stay with the id inside the request, you MUST check that the user id is the same as the connected user, anyways, for me the 1 is redundant because you already have that information, plus, every time you are going to make useless checks because anyways the authentified userId is the one that you are going to trust in all cases.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

REST is resources oriented so in your point what is the resource user or book. My point of view it's book. And I think you can request this resources
/api/books?user={userid}
But this URL can not solve your permission issue so you have to do it in your code with token information you can get with a OAuth2 protocol or whatever.